# Replace value in dataframe just by using panda (without the use of numpy)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df as shown below.

```
INDEX NAME    AGE  HEIGHT  ENGLISH  
0     a      19.0       5      NaN     
1     g      NaN        2    100.0   
2     j      82.0       2     NaN
```

I want to replace the 'NaN' under AGE with the mean of ages and 'NaN' under English with two other values.
Is this possible **without** using numpy and just using pandas?

Comment: `and 'NaN' under English with two other values`, which values?

Comment: I have to replace first one under English by 21 and the last by 76.

Comment: sorry for that. Actually it has to be replaced by the marks in English. The sample values can be anything between [ 0 to 100].

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is "without numpy" a requirement? Notice that [pandas has numpy as a hard dependency](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py), so if you can use pandas, you can use numpy.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If yes upvoting and marking as accepted answer is encouraged. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using `df['column_name'].mean()`. Combine this with the `fillna()` function and you will get what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [19.0, np.nan, 82.0], 'ENGLISH' : [np.nan, 100.0, np.nan]})

df.fillna(value = {'Age' : df['Age'].mean(), 'ENGLISH' : df['ENGLISH'].mean()},
          inplace = True)
```

---

```
     Age   ENGLISH
0   19.0    100.0
1   50.5    100.0
2   82.0    100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is:

```
df.loc[df['AGE'].isna(), 'AGE'] = df['AGE'].mean()
df.loc[df['ENGLISH'].isna(), 'ENGLISH'] = [21, 76]
```

As you can see, the syntax quite similar to that of numpy. Instead of indexing columns with integer indices, you index the columns with their specific names. Additionaly using `.loc` should be prefered over directly assigning the values to avoid the annoying (and sometimes helpful) "assigning value to a copy" error.